# AngularJS: Where to include module

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 modules. The main app module and two directive modules. All modules are dependent on ngAnimate.

How should I best include the ngAnimate?

In the first main app module only, like the code below? Here it looks as they are in one file, but they are really in 3 different files.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate','someDirectiveModule','someOtherDirectiveModule']);
angular.module('someDirectiveModule', []);
angular.module('someOtherDirectiveModule', []);
```

Or separately in each module that is dependent on ngAnimate (which in this case is all modules)? Like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate','someDirectiveModule','someOtherDirectiveModule']);
angular.module('someDirectiveModule', ['ngAnimate']);
angular.module('someOtherDirectiveModule', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Comment: 1st option would be preferable as per me, injecting it one time will be better than injecting `ngAnimate` thrice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EricC Does your first approch work? I doubt. It is mandatory to inject dependencies in every module that needs it.

Comment: When I think of it, I probably have not, just assumed that it would work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate','someDirectiveModule','someOtherDirectiveModule']);
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate','someDirectiveModule','someOtherDirectiveModule']);
angular.module('someOtherDirectiveModule', ['ngAnimate']);
```

if you'll use "someDirectiveModule" or "someOtherDirectiveModule"  in other app without "ngAnimate"